# Onclicking button change className of the clicked Button and another Button | ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have an React component with two buttons. When user clicks left button, it should change the class of the left button, also the class of the right button and also it will render ListView component. Likewise, when the user clicks right button, it should change the class of the right button, also the class of the left button and also it will render MapView component. I have tried some ways in the below code. Please let me know, what i am missing and let me know to achieve that.

Thanks in Advance.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Typography, withStyles, Button} from '@material-ui/core';
import ListView from './listView/ListView';
import MapView from './mapView/mapView';

const styles = {
    boardHeader: {
        display: 'flex'
    },
    boardTitle: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: 500,
        color: '#ED8E34'
    },
    buttonList: {
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderRadius: 50,
        fontSize: 12,
        minHeight: 10,
        padding: '0px 30px',
        boxShadow: 'none'
    },
    buttonMap: {
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderRadius: 50,
        fontSize: 12,
        minHeight: 10,
        padding: '0px 30px',
        boxShadow: 'none',
        marginLeft: '-10px'
    },
    activeButtonList: {
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderRadius: 50,
        fontSize: 12,
        minHeight: 10,
        padding: '0px 30px',
        zIndex: 1
    },
    activeButtonMap: {
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderRadius: 50,
        fontSize: 12,
        minHeight: 10,
        padding: '0px 30px',
        marginLeft: '-10px'
    },

};

class BoardContent extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            active: 1,
        }
    }
    onClickList = (e, active) => {
        this.setState({active})
    }
  render() {
      const { classes } = this.props
      const { active } = this.state
    return (
      <div> 
        <div className={classes.boardHeader}>
            <Typography className={classes.boardTitle}>Select the View</Typography>
            <div>
                <Button variant="contained" size="small" className={active === 1 ? classes.activeButtonList : classes.buttonList} onClick={this.onClickList}>LIST VIEW</Button>
                <Button variant="contained" size="small" className={active === 2 ? classes.activeButtonMap : classes.buttonMap} onClick={this.onClickList}>MAP VIEW</Button> 
            </div>
        </div>
        {active === 1 ? <ListView /> : null}
        {active === 2 ? <MapView /> : null}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(BoardContent);
```

Comment: I think you should have two onClicks handlers for both the buttons and in each change the value of 'active' accordingly so,eg when button 2 is clicked change the state of 'active' to 2.

On the onClick handler's parameters, the 'active' serves no purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `active` to `this.onClickList`. So instead of `onClick={this.onClickList}` you could do something like `onClick={event => this.onClickList(event, 1)}` for the list view button and `onClick={event => this.onClickList(event, 2)}` for the map view button.

You could also have separate methods for each button.

```
handleListViewClick = () => setState({ active: 1 })
handleMapViewClick = () => setState({ active: 2 })
```

And your onClicks will be something like

```
... onClick={handleListViewClick} />
... onClick={handleMapViewClick} />
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Button` component, you need to bind `this` and the value you want to set to `active` in your event handler.

Either do this

```
onClick={this.onClickList.bind(this, 1)} // for list button
onClick={this.onClickList.bind(this, 2)} // for map button
```

or

```
onClick={(e) => this.onClickList(e, 1)} // for list button
onClick={(e) => this.onClickList(e, 2)} // for map button
```